# Is there any method to click an svg element in selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium, svg

Actually I am trying to make an `instabot` using Selenium in PyCharm and trying to hit like button, but I am unable to trigger that like button due to it's svg property, if anyone know how to click on that like button please help me out.

Here's the code:

```
def findhashtag(self):
    self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'+self.hashtag+'/')
    like_picture = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div')
    like_picture.click() #this is to open picture
    elememnt = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", '//*[local-name()="svg"][@class="_8-yf5"]')))
    #self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="wp06b"]//*[name()="svg"]').click() #another method to click on that
    #self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="viewBox" and @class="_8-yf5")').click() #another method to click on that
    #self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Like").click() #another method to click on that
    follow = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Follow"]'))
    follow.click() #this is to follow and its working fine
    try:
        like_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="wp06b"]//*[name()="svg"]'))
        like_button.click() #trying to clic[enter image description here][1]k on like button
    except:
        print("not liked")
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834459/programmatically-trigger-click-event-in-svg-rect-element/49835939#49835939) help. SVG elements don't have an onclick method but you can work around that, at leat in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you change 'find element by XPath' to Element to be clickable.

```
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  

    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '#XPATH here'))).click()
    except:
        print('this did not work')
```