# Why selector.click() function its not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

I have a menu with contact page and i want a button from home page when its clicked to actually click on my contact button from menu and its not working:

here is the **menu with contact button ( li_contact or i_contact )**:

```
<svg id="demo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="220" viewBox="0 0 382 80">

        <rect id="stretchy" x="20" y="30" width="60" height="60" rx="8px" ry="8px" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <g id="icons">
            <g>
                <rect class="li_house" x="20" y="30" width="60" height="60" rx="8px" ry="8px" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
                <image class="i_house" x="25" y="20" width="50" height="80" xlink:href="./img/svg/menu/home.svg" />
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect class="li_proiecte" x="170" y="30" width="60" height="60" rx="8px" ry="8px"
                    stroke-miterlimit="10" />
                <image class="i_proiecte" x="180" y="20" width="40" height="80"
                    xlink:href="./img/svg/menu/innovation.svg" />
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect class="li_contact" x="320" y="30" width="60" height="60" rx="8px" ry="8px"
                    stroke-miterlimit="10" />
                <image class="i_contact" x="330" y="20" width="40" height="80"
                    xlink:href="./img/svg/menu/contact.svg" />
            </g>
            
        </g>
    </svg>
```

and here is the **button**:

```
<span class="mover" >Drop me a line</span>
```

I can't make the span button to redirect to the contact page because if i do that, menu animation will remain on home

- you can check on my page: https://www.ptaran.com/ *

here its the code i have tried:

```
$( ".mover" ).click(function() {
    $(".li_contact").trigger("click");
});
```

```
$( ".mover" ).click(function() {
    $(".li_contact").click();
});
```

```
var mover = document.querySelector(".mover");
var svg = document.querySelector("#demo");
var cont_b = svg.querySelector(".li_contact");

mover.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  cont_b.click();
});
```

all of there are not working

this is the ***animation code***:

```
let targets = gsap.utils.toArray("#icons g");
let targetStarts = [20, 170, 320];
let anim;
let activeDot = 0;
let targetDot;
let maxDur = 0.6;

targets.forEach((obj, i) => {
  obj.index = i;
  obj.addEventListener("click", letsStretch);
});

function letsStretch() {
  targetDot = this.index;
  if (targetDot != activeDot) {
    if (anim && anim.isActive()) {
      anim.progress(1);
    }

    let oldX = targetStarts[activeDot];
    let newX = targetStarts[targetDot];
    let travel = Math.abs(oldX - newX);
    let factor = gsap.utils.mapRange(100, 500, 0.5, 1, travel);
    let dur = maxDur * factor;

    anim = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { duration: dur, ease: "back.in(2)" } });
    if (newX > oldX) {
      anim.to("#stretchy", {
        attr: { width: travel + 60 }
      });

      anim.to(
        "#stretchy",
        { attr: { x: newX, width: 60 }, ease: "back" },
        "+=0.08"
      );
    } else {
      anim.to("#stretchy", {
        attr: { x: newX, width: travel + 60 }
      });
      anim.to("#stretchy", { attr: { width: 60 }, ease: "back" }, "+=0.08");
    }

    anim.to(
      "#stretchy",
      {
        duration: dur,
        ease: "sine.inOut",
        attr: { height: 30, y: 45 },
        yoyo: true,
        repeat: 1
      },
      0
    );
  } else {
    return;
  }

  activeDot = targetDot;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [programmatically trigger click event in svg rect element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834459/programmatically-trigger-click-event-in-svg-rect-element)

Comment: TL;DR: use the last code snippet in your question but replace `cont_b.click();` with `cont_b.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));`.

Comment: Its working but the animation its not moving. When you physically click, the animation its moving. You can look here, i made a gif: https://gyazo.com/0cded01d37be82b605295e7d12ba45b4

Comment: I'm assuming that it is because that animation is not triggered via the event listener on the `rect` element but presumably on the parent `g` element. You'll need trigger that one as well in that case. (Or move those events to listen to the same element.)

Comment: You are right but still I don't know how could i do that, I added the animation code to the question

Comment: The quickest fix would be to add another line after the `dispatchEvent` I mentioned above with `cont_b.parentElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));`. Whether that is the most beautiful way is up for debate.

Comment: Thank you man, you made my day. Everything its working now. You are awesome