# Both click() and dispatchEvent does not trigger automatic click in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a react component that has an SVG image. I have divided the SVG into multiple react box. I have query selector which selects all the react box and JS click event to auto click that react.

I tried working with both `click` and `dispatch event`. But none of them works in my scenario.

Below is the section of the code I am working on.

```
componentDidMount() {
    var element =  document.querySelectorAll("square");
    for(var i = 0; i<element.length; i++) {
      element[i].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    }
}

render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="col-12">
          <svg  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <image xlinkHref={imageFile}  height="100%" width="100%" />
            <g><rect className="square" x="10" y="10" width="20" height="10" fillOpacity=".2"  onClick={() =>console.log("clicked")}></rect> </g>         
            <g><rect className="square" x="30" y="10" width="20" height="10" fillOpacity=".4"  onClick={() =>console.log("clicked")}></rect> </g>              
          </svg>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
```

}

I also tried using the `click()` function and did not work for SVG images and also is there a way we could automate a click in each square every 10 seconds?

Comment: in your example you have put the Onclick inside the fillOpacity, so it won't work.

Comment: I have added closing ". While my code has the closing ". And it was not the issue.

Comment: Why do you need to simulate clicks in the first place?

Comment: I have model attached on each square. So user don't have to click on the screen as automatic clip would trigger the model for each square. @mzedeler

Comment: I am using <rect> element. On click function works when I manually click. But does not use when I target that class with click() function.@RobertLongson

Comment: @madhavkoirala saw multiple `})}` in the code. Had to edit it to remove the syntax issue. Please verify if that code snippet is actually valid.

Comment: This [works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834459/programmatically-trigger-click-event-in-svg-rect-element/49835939#49835939) FWIW

Comment: That sounds like a non-optimal design. You shouldn't use click events in stead of function calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a `.` in the query selector so the node list was actually empty.

If you want to automate a click in each square every 10 seconds, this code does the trick:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

const intervalsIdentifiers = Array.from(elements).map(x => setInterval(() => x.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')), 10000));
```

The `dispatchEvent` method is indeed the only way, because the `rect` element doesn't have a `click` method (only HTML elements do, not SVG elements) as demonstrated below:

```js
console.log('click' in SVGRectElement.prototype); // false

console.log(HTMLElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('click')); // true

console.log(HTMLButtonElement.prototype instanceof HTMLElement); // true (a button has the click method)
console.log(SVGRectElement.prototype instanceof HTMLElement); // false
```

The full working code (native JavaScript but should work as well with React in the `componentDidMount` hook):

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

const intervalsIdentifiers = Array.from(elements).map(x => setInterval(() => x.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')), 10000));
```

```html
<div className="col-12">
  <svg  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <image xlink:Href="https://img-19.ccm2.net/8vUCl8TXZfwTt7zAOkBkuDRHiT8=/1240x/smart/b829396acc244fd484c5ddcdcb2b08f3/ccmcms-commentcamarche/20494859.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%" />
    <g><rect class="square" x="10" y="10" width="20" height="10" fillOpacity=".2"  onclick="console.log('clicked')"></rect> </g>         
    <g><rect class="square" x="30" y="10" width="20" height="10" fillOpacity=".4"  onclick="console.log('clicked')"></rect> </g>              
  </svg>
</div>
```